# Does python cache the instance variables or does it calculate them every time they are called

Tags: python

Say I have a dataframe that I populate it by loading a json file and then doing some manipulation on that file etc. When I'm calling `self.df` in other methods, does `get_dataframe` get called every time? Or is it part of the object and is cached?

```
import pandas as pd
import json

class A():
  def __init__(self):
    self.df = self.get_dataframe() 

  def get_dataframe(self): # is this called every time?
    data = json.load(open('filename'))
    dict = self.prepare_json(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

    return df

 def use_df(self):
   self.df["new_column"] = ..

 def use_df2(self):
   self.df.plot()...
```

As a second question. I also wonder if there is a difference in performance between these 2 classes where I'm calling the get_labels method every time vs. I'm storing the labels as an instance property:

```
class B():

  def get_labels(self):
    labels = ..
    return labels

  def use_labels(self):
    labels = self.get_labels()
    # use labels here

  def use_labels2(self):
    labels = self.get_labels()
    # use labels here

class B2():
  def __init__(self):
    self.labels = self.get_labels()

  def get_labels(self):
    labels = ..
    return labels

  def use_labels(self):
    labels = self.labels
    # use labels here

  def use_labels2(self):
    labels = self.labels
    # use labels here
```

I'm wondering if python would cache the `get_labels()` result so it will not make any difference in performance...

Comment: No, it assumes absolutely nothing about your code and data. Everything is rerun again. Why not just make it an attribute if it is not likely to change?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so there are no differences in terms of performance between B() and B2() or are you just referring to A()?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was looking at B only. In B2's case, you call the function once, and store the result in an instance attribute. So, when you refer to `self.labels`, that method is not called again, only the variable's value is queried. That is more performant, I suppose.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ok, so in case of A() the function is called only once because we store the result in an instance attribute? ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm calling `self.df` in other methods, does `get_dataframe` get
>   called every time?

No, because `self.df` is evaluated at the time of object instantiation. After that, subsequent references to `self.df` will only query the value it references, and will not call the method repeatedly. (Hint: you can confirm this by adding a couple of print statements here and there.)

Going along the same lines, `B2` would be more performant than `B` since it caches the method's result inside an instance attribute in `__init__`.